# nested if/else inside Switch Statement

Tags: c, if-statement, nested, switch-statement

I'm trying to nest a if/else inside a case switch statement. When I enter case 'p' or 'P' no matter what character is typed the $15.00 line is printed. I have tried moving/adding {}'s with no change in output.

Thanks for taking time to help a noob out.

Entire code now here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
//variable declarations 
char typeOfWash, tireShine;

//Menu
printf("R ---> Regular ($5.00)\n");
printf("B ---> Bronze ($7.50)\n");
printf("G ---> Gold ($10.25)\n");
printf("P ---> Platinum ($15.00)\n");
printf("Tire Shine can be added to the Gold or Platinum ONLY,");
printf("for an additional$2.50\n\n");

printf("Enter your selection: ");
scanf("%c",&typeOfWash);

switch (typeOfWash)
{
    case 'R': case 'r':
        printf("Your bill total is: $5.00\n");
        break;
    case 'B': case 'b':
        printf("Your bill total is: $7.50\n");
        break;
    case 'G': case 'g':
        printf("Would you Like a Tire Shine? (Y/N): ");
        scanf("%c ",&tireShine);
        if (tireShine == 'Y' || tireShine == 'y')
            printf("Your bill total is: $12.75\n");
        else
            printf("Your bill total is: $10.25\n");
        break;
    case 'P': case 'p':
        printf("Would you Like a Tire Shine? (Y/N): ");
        scanf("%c ",&tireShine);
        printf("%c",tireShine);
        if (tireShine == 'Y' || tireShine == 'y')
            printf("Your bill total is: $17.50\n");
        else
            printf("Your bill total is: $15.00\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid Choice");

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you print out the value of tireShine?

Comment: Also, you can do if ( toupper(tireShine) == 'Y' )

Comment: Your 15$ or 17.5$ depends upon Y or y but not on P or p.

Comment: `toupper()` returns the upper case of the ASCII char you invoke it with.

Comment: this is a small section of code, P or p stands for platinum which costs $15 base and +$2.50 for an added tire shine. Like I said, I can enter this case, and all others fine, it's just executing the $17.50 line if &tireShine == 'y' or 'Y'.

Comment: Post the declaration of "tireShine"

Comment: I updated the OP with the full code. it's near the top. it reads:
char typeOfWash, tireShine;

Comment: Try to print "tireShine" in each of the if-else condition before printing the "bill total" statement.

Comment: as you can see i'm trying to do that in the p case, y statement, but it's just skipping over that printf() and printing the $17.50 line.

Comment: your C compiler seems to allow for an extended syntax concerning `case` labels. Standard C only allows one label per statement. You'd have to put an `;` after the first label to make it an "empty" statement that is labeled.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt, I'm sorry I don't follow. I'm using visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that using `scanf` with the `%c` format specifier results in white space not being consumed, which in your case results in a `\n` being left in the input buffer. What your instructor seems to have suggested is to eat the trailing white space from the initial input with the next `scanf`; however, I suspect that they said to insert a leading space rather than a trailing space as this fixes your problem:

```
scanf(" %c", &tireShine);
```

Alternatively, you could use `getchar()` immidiately before your second `scanf` and consume the new line character beforehand:

```
getchar();
scanf("%c", &tireShine);
```

A second alternative would be to use the `%s` format specifier instead of `%c` and handle it accordingly.

Be warned that `getchar()` will only consume one character from the input buffer. If a user were to input a string longer than 1 character, for example, you would need to have something like `while ((x = getchar()) != '\n') ;` to clear the buffer.

Comment: Thank You @tojrobinson; I am learning C and while I wasn't have a problem with a switch I was having a problem using a nested else if to if with a couple of scanf's that took in characters and I was effected by the same issue my program was ending right before the if statement and I couldn't figure out WHY?!?  I added the space in the scanf( " %c", variable) and that worked!  It seemed to be picking up my carriage return best I could tell?  getchar(); right before the scanf statement also seemed to work but I assume the space is the preferred method?

Answer (score 0):

Try inline if.

```
case 'P': case 'p':
    printf("Would you Like a Tire Shine? (Y/N): ");
    scanf("%c",&tireShine);
    printf("Your bill total is: $%s\n", toUpper(tireShine) == 'Y' ? "17.50":"15.00");
    break;
```

Comment: Tried that, output for P to enter case, then Y, is: $15.000000

Comment: is tireShine a char * or a char? Because in the case of char * you should try check "Y" and it the case of char you should check 'Y'.

Comment: it's just a char, please see the OP again. I put my full code there.

Comment: Does the same happen if you put a char * in there, i mean a string? char* tireShine and scanf("%s",tireShine); and ofcourse then check for "Y" or "y"

Comment: char* tireShine; in variable declaration?

Comment: as you say, the variable declaration.

Comment: okay, I just made those changes and i'm still getting just the $15 line printed.

Answer (score 0):

You have one more space.

Change

```
scanf("%c ", &tireShine);
```

to

```
scanf("%c", &tireShine);
```

Comment: I need the space or it doesn't allow for user input. And that's how my instructure said to do it for now.

Comment: @user1699174 Why it doesn't allow for use input? Check the `tireShine` right after scanf see what you get.

Comment: just tried to print right after scanf() and it skips it and prints $15 line.

Comment: @user1699174: It doesn't skip it, it prints the `\n` that the `scanf` read into `tireShine`. If you remove the `printf`, you should notice that your "Would you like..." and "Your bill..." should be on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
printf("Enter your selection: ");
scanf("%c",&typeOfWash);
fflush(stdin) ;
```

But avoid using it.
**UPDATED**::

```
printf("Enter your selection: ");
scanf("%c",&typeOfWash);
getchar() ;
```

As, **fflush(stdin)** will result in **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR**, you can use **getchar()** to clear the stream.

Comment: We have a winner!  Thanks for everyone who played along.

Now what exactly is this? and how does it work?

Comment: It worked. Why avoid using it? what else would I have done to fix my problem?

Comment: This is not a winning answer. fflush(stdin) ; shouldn't be used frequently. Try googling it. fflush flushes the data at stream to be forced to be written.

Comment: -1. This is wrong. `fflush(stdin)` results in **Undefined Behavior**.

Comment: You can update your question now. Try asking why not to use it or what is the other alternative. I really do not know :-(

Comment: Thanks for your answer though. This is the only thing that has worked for me. When I turn my assignment (using fflush) into my professor, I'll ask him about this and will post back here later.

Comment: @Als- Yeah I know, but don't you think explaining it better and giving an alternative would be better than downvoting :-(

Comment: The answer from tojrobinson is better than mine.

Comment: Don't take downvotes personally.They are a means of indicating support or apprehension towards a answer.When I downvoted this answer was incorrect and it was marked as the selected answer.It was necessary to let know that the answer is wrong.As for the correct approach couple of answers here already had done that so I didn't feel the need to explain again.

Comment: @Als- Yep I got that. Anyways, it was my bad :-)

Answer (score 0):

One problem with scanf() is that it typically leaves the 'return' unread. Therefore if you enter something like a 'p' then a 'return', it reads and processes the 'p' but not the 'return'. The second call to scanf() reads the 'return' char which was already there and so it does not match 'y' or 'Y'. You have the same problem on case 'g'. It does not matter if you use "%c" or "%c ". This problem may be worse on DOS systems which have two chars to mark the end of line.